# Does Azure Storage Explorer not support a setup with activated conditional access?

Tags: multi-factor-authentication, azure-authentication, azure-storage-explorer

I get the "You can't get there from here" error, when using the Azure Storage Explorer. We use MFA and Conditional Access.
The default browser is Edge: if I click on a link, e.g. in an E-mail in Outlook, Edge opens up. Latest version.

In the details I see:

```
Device identifier: Not available
Device platform: Windows 10
Device state: Unregistered
```

So, it looks like the Azure Storage Explorer or Edge have problems to access the session data or the device ID. Other applications like SharePoint, Skype, Outlook can authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, Conditional Access is not supported for the Azure Storage Explorer.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-explorer-troubleshooting?tabs=Windows%2C2004

[image]